# Django: Change MinLengthValidator Error Message

Tags: django

Here is how MinLengthValidator is defined in Django:

```
class MinLengthValidator(BaseValidator):
    compare = lambda self, a, b: a < b
    clean = lambda self, x: len(x)
    message = ungettext_lazy(
        'Ensure this value has at least %(limit_value)d character (it has %(show_value)d).',
        'Ensure this value has at least %(limit_value)d characters (it has %(show_value)d).',
        'limit_value')
    code = 'min_length'
```

I tried changing the error message in my code like this:

```
password_min_length_validator = MinLengthValidator(8)
password_min_length_validator.message = ungettext_lazy(
    'Ensure password has at least %(limit_value)d character (it has %(show_value)d).',
    'Ensure password has at least %(limit_value)d characters (it has %(show_value)d).',
    'limit_value')
```

But I am getting this error:

```
ugettext() takes exactly 1 argument (3 given)
```

I am doing it the same way django.core.validators does it.

Comment: Provide full stacktrace please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're using an earlier version of Django, so you should base your code on the `MinLengthValidator` for your Django version, and not the current implementation. You are getting the error because the `ungettext_lazy` method changed in Django 1.6 (see ticket [#19160](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/19160)).

For example, in Django 1.5.X, you would do:

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

class MinLengthValidator(BaseValidator):
    compare = lambda self, a, b: a < b
    clean = lambda self, x: len(x)
    message = _('Ensure this value has at least %(limit_value)d characters (it has %(show_value)d).')
    code = 'min_length'

password_min_length_validator = MinLengthValidator(8)
password_min_length_validator.message = _(
    'Ensure password has at least %(limit_value)d characters (it has %(show_value)d).',
)
```

Instead of setting the messages attribute after you instantiate the validator, you could subclass it:

```
class MyMinLengthValidator(MinLengthValidator):
    message = _('Ensure my_field has at least %(limit_value)d characters (it has %(show_value)d).')

my_min_length_validator = MyMinLengthValidator(8)
```

Alternatively, you could use `error_messages` option on the form field:

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    my_field = forms.CharField(validators=[MinLengthValidator(8)], 
                        error_messages={'min_length': _('Ensure my_field has at least %(limit_value)d characters (it has %(show_value)d).')
})
```